# imageIcon/image load in frame?

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I made a image lists like this in java:

```
static String[] imageList1 = { "images/bgs/bg.png", "images/bgs/image1.png", 
       "images/bgs/image2.png", "images/bgs/image3.png" };
```

I use the image in the image list as a background like this:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(imageList1[0]));
```

The problem is when I run the program the whole frame was blank(supposedly the frame consists from only one picture `image` and one `button`)  but if I minimize and then maximize or adjust the width or height of the frame, it suddenly shows the `image` and the `button`.

Comment: you can not use Jlabel as a background image..

Comment: Did you `setVisible()` _before_ or _after_ adding the `JLabel`? Consider posting a simple runnable example for help faster. As of now, we can only make guesses.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `revalidate(); repaint();` ?

That might fix your issue, but what you are looking for is the JImagePanel class. It is a third-party util and should make your life much easier. [Get the source here.](https://github.com/dberm22/DBoard/blob/master/src/com/dberm22/utils/JImagePanel.java)

Then, just add this panel to the root of the JFrame and viola!

Comment: I recommend calling `repaint()` after setting the `JLabel`'s icon. `revalidate()` only makes sense if you're altering the component hierarchy.